# ARC/ObjC++: ObjC objects as C++ member variable

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++

ARC/ObjC++: ObjC objects as C++ member variable

Consider

```
class SomeCppClass {
    NSLock * someLock ;
    public:
    SomeCppClass() {
        someLock = [[NSLock alloc] init] ;
    }
    void atomicInsert(SomeOtherCppClass * c) {
        [someLock lock] ;
        // do atomic C++ stuff
        [someLock unlock] ;
    }

    ~SomeCppClass() {
        // ? Huh ?
        // ? can I just say:
        someLock = 0 ;
        // ?
    }
}
```

Guess I had to encounter the opposite case of my previous question :-)

Comment: You don't need to assign \0 to someLock in the dtor. Is that your question? (I didn't read your other question)

Comment: My question is: how/when do I deallocate an ObjC object from a C++ context. Pre-ARC, I just had to [someLock release] ; and that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under ARC, when the instance of SomeCppClass is destroyed, someLock will be released automatically. This will happen whether or not you define your own destructor.

You don't need to assign nil/null to that member in your destructor.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't clear to me how the C++ side of things was dealing with this. I am assuming your answer to be valid for Objective-C++, but not for straight C++, as std cpp wouldn't be able to deal with anything ObjC except for void *, right?

Comment: Right. In general anytime you have a pointer to an ObjC object stuffed in a void*, then you've either obtained that outside of ARC's control or bridge cast it out of ARC's control. So you're on your own there as usual.